# Index is not changing in Drop Down Menu C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, indexing, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` which is filled up from database. When I select a record on index 1, it comes up with right results but when I select second index, it comes up with same index. it looks like `DropDownList` shows First Index as by default. How can I select change index in `DropDownList`?
So if would select index 3 the result must be from index 3.
I have tried `DropDownList.SelectedItem`,`DropDownList.SelectedValue`,`DropDownList.SelectedIndex`,`DropDownList.Text` but No effect seems to be there.

**DropDownList Loading on Page_Load**

```
 public void load_Individual()
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sdaIndividual = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_trip", _connectionString);
            DataTable dtIndividual = new DataTable();
            sdaIndividual.Fill(dtIndividual);
            if (dtIndividual.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddl_Individual.DataTextField = "TruckNo";
                ddl_Individual.DataValueField = "TruckNo";
                ddl_Individual.DataSource = dtIndividual;
                ddl_Individual.DataBind();
            } 
        }
    }
```

**DropDownList For Selecting Values**

```
if (ddl_Individual.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            ddl_Individual.ClearSelection();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select * , '' as c1, '' as c2, 0 as c3 , 0 as c4 , 0 as c5 , 0 as c6, 0 as c7 , 0 as c8 from tbl_Trip 
            where TruckNo='" + ddl_Individual.SelectedValue + "'", _connectionString);
            adp.Fill(Dt);
            Session["mydata"] = Dt;
            Response.Redirect("LoadReport.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),"alertMessage","aler('select valid value')", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ddl_Individual.ClearSelection();
```

This line is clearing the selection in the dropdown before you have a chance to read what value the user has selected.  Remove it as I see no need for it.

Make sure to set the items in the page load by checking for a postback:

```
if(!IsPostBack)   
{
    // Perform binding
}
```

If the dropdown should trigger the postback then be sure to set the `AutoPostBack = true;`

Also, look into using parameterized queries to help prevent SQL injection attacks.  This is a good habit to develop regardless of the size of the application.

Comment: I have tried this, but there is no effect. kindly share an alternate solution please

Comment: Actually my application is a small application and there is no need to use Sql Injection. So would you like to share an other alternate?